Android emulator keeps playing outdated code
About 50% of the time I run my Compose app in the emulator, I watch the build and my app restarts, but what runs is some previously cached, outdated version of my app, typically from 5 or 10 changes ago. Then I simply re-run, and the latest changes are reflected. Sometimes, I can then re-rerun, and the ghost version will reappear again!
Android Studio features a form of 'hot reload' for Compose that can skip the build step depending on the type of changes. This isn't what I'm referring to. It happens only when I click the Run button.
I can do a Clean & Rebuild, but as I said, about 50% of all my builds are failing this way, so constantly cleaning and rebuilding isn't a viable solution.

What exactly is failing when you clean and rebuild?

Maybe this is a bug in the new Android Studio version. I am facing the same problem. This is an annoying one.

@tomerpacific clean and rebuild fails to prevent the problem - afterward, running the emulator still loads a ghost/cached/outdated version of the app about 50% of the time.

I also had this happening a few times. It appears that this is a bug in Android Studio Koala. The issue you are describing was reported on the Google Issue Tracker, but closed as the issue creator did not provide sufficient information to debug the issue.
If you have this issue in 50% of the time, please consider opening a new ticket with sufficient information so that the Android Team can resolve it. In your case, I would recommend the following steps:

Start a screen recording of Android Studio where both code and emulator are visible
Run the app, make a small obvious change in the code, rerun the app
Repeat steps 1 and 2 until you actually have recorded the issue happening
Afterwards, once you were able to reproduce the issue on video, immediately collect the diagnostics data.


Attach the video and the diagnostics.zip file to your issue. Then drop the link to your newly created issue in a comment here so we can upvote your issue.
